# For references for ball simplex picking

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, geometry, reference-request

Today my group of student were discussing about a problem as **ball simplex picking** problem. Specifically, we have:

Given a $n$ dimentional Euclidean ball, and we pick $d\le n+1$ points inside it uniformly random. The $d$ points forms a $d-1$ dimentional simplex (with probability $1$.) What is the expected volume of the simplex?

We try to find the references for this problem (we believe that this problem is richly researched.) We try to search for the results about this problem. Here are some of the references I have got, but I have not find it full. I would like to seek for help in this Stack Exchange Community.

For $d=1$, and on spheres:

> Tu, S.-J. and Fischbach, E. "A New Geometric Probability Technique for an N-Dimensional Sphere and Its Applications" 17 Apr 2000. http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0004021.

For $d=n$ (from the Corollary 1)

> Buchta, C. and Müller, J. "Random Polytopes in a Ball." J. Appl. Prob. 21, 753-762, 1984.

By this link, I think the answer of $d,n$ equals to the number of $d+1,d$ times the mean of secent, as in this paper (but I couild not find the value in this paper)

> Kingman, J. F. C. "Random Secants of a Convex Body." J. Appl. Prob. 6, 660-672, 1969.

All of these references are produced by the Math World links, such as this:

> Weisstein, Eric W. "Ball Triangle Picking." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallTrianglePicking.html

The Math World link contains the results for small $n,d$'s.

I hope there is a result for the problem directly here... Thanks for the community for help again!

Comment: For the general solution, see Miles, Roger E. "Isotropic random simplices." Advances in Applied Probability 3.2 (1971): 353-382.